# Compact Framework C# loading DLL dynamically

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework

instead of including a dll file in my project as a reference, I need to dynamically use some classes from specific namespaces in that dll file.

I've done some research about the topic and found the way to do that by using Activator, InvokeMember and so on.

But, i have a problem with writing proper code. I need to do something like:

```
A a = new A();

B[] b = a.method();

B b0 = b[0];
```

where A and B are type of classes from namespace in dynamically loaded dll file.

I'm trying to adjust that piece of code:

```
var DLL = Assembly.Load(path_to_dll);

//here variables to use later

foreach(Type type in DLL.GetTypes())
{
    //here checking if type is what I want and:
    var c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    type.InvokeMember("method", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c, null);
}
```

I don't know how to use InvokeMember to return array of specified in DLL type. In addition I need two variables of unknown type (which be known in runtime) to be visible in whole method block.

Please give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the member is done as normal - but you can then cast the result to `IList`:

```
IList array = (IList) type.InvokeMember(...);
object firstElement = array[0];
```

(All arrays implement `IList`, which is slightly simper to use in this case than `Array`.)

You can't use the actual type as the type of the variable, because you don't know about it at compile-time. If you know that the type will implement some appropriate interface which you have access to, you could use that:

```
IFoo firstElement = (IFoo) array[0];
```

Comment: Thank You for a reply. So there is no way to use methods of object "array[0]" if it doesn't implement any interface?